# Deleting message from folder in javamail

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am trying to remove/delete a message from a folder in Java mail (after I have copied it to another) here is my code:

```
Flags deleted = new Flags("DELETED");  
folder.setFlags(messages, deleted, true);  
folder.expunge();
```

The message is not affected.  Can someone please show me the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Flags deleted = new Flags(Flags.Flag.DELETED);
folder.setFlags(messages, deleted, true);
folder.expunge(); // or folder.close(true);
```